# Select Groups Where the First Value Equals "x" in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data.table, conditional-statements

I want to do a conditional slice on a grouped data set in R.

```
df <- data.frame(grp = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 vehicle = c("car", "boat", "bike", "car", "plane", "bike"))

#>    grp  vehicle
#> 1    1      car
#> 2    1     boat
#> 3    2     bike
#> 4    2      car
#> 5    3    plane
#> 6    3     bike
```

I would like to group by `grp` and only keep groups where the first row is equal to `car`. This would be the solution.

```
#>   grp  vehicle
#> 1   1      car
#> 2   1     boat
```

How do I do this? I think it could be a better version of this.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% filter(any(slice_head(vehicle == "car")))

#, Error in `filter()`:
#, ! Problem while computing `..1 =
...
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(grp) %>% filter(vehicle[1] == 'car')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done without a grouping as well i.e. with `duplicated` to find the first occurrence of 'grp' and check if the 'vehicle' value is "car" and use that to create a logical with 'grp'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(grp %in% grp[!duplicated(grp) & vehicle == "car"])
  grp vehicle
1   1     car
2   1    boat
```

Answer (score 2):

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df) # setDT is more canonical
DT[, .SD[first(vehicle) == "car",], by = .(grp)]
#      grp vehicle
#    <num>  <char>
# 1:     1     car
# 2:     1    boat
```

Answer (score 2):

Another data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, if(first(vehicle)=="car") .SD, by=grp]

     grp vehicle
   <num>  <char>
1:     1     car
2:     1    boat
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option using `unique` + `rowid`

```
> setDT(df)[grp %in% unique(grp)[vehicle[rowid(grp) == 1] == "car"]]
   grp vehicle
1:   1     car
2:   1    boat
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is provided in the comments courtesy of @Darren Tsai.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% filter(vehicle[1] == "car")
```